# java: adding one value to one column in a 2D-array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D-array to which I have to add a certain value, but only to one column of the 2D-array. One row of the 2D-array has to skipted and will stay the same as before.

I already have a code (see below), but that is just adding the value, not calculating it.

My code so far:

```
double lowest = Double.parseDouble(excelMatrix[0][0]);
    int row = 0, column = 0;
    List usedRow = new ArrayList(); 
    for(int r = 0; r<excelMatrix.length-1; r++){

        for(int c = 0; c<excelMatrix[r].length; c++){
            double number = Double.parseDouble(excelMatrix[r][c]);
            if(lowest > number) {
                lowest = number;
                row = r;
                column = c;
            }                   
        }                       
    }                       
    usedRow.add(row);

for(int r = 0; r < excelMatrix.length; r++){
   if( r != row)
   excelMatrix[r][column] += lowest;
}
```

The initial matrix looks something like this:

```
{1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5}  
{5 , 4 , 3 , 2 , 1}  
{4 , 5 , 1 , 2 , 3}  
{2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 1}     
{3 , 4 , 5 , 1 , 2}
```

and by adding 10 to column 3, except row 3, I would like to get:

```
{1 , 2 , 3 , 14 , 5}  
{5 , 4 , 3 , 12 , 1}  
{4 , 5 , 1 , 12 , 3}  
{2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 1}  
{3 , 4 , 5 , 11 , 2}
```

But at the moment I am getting:

```
{1 , 2 , 3 , 410 , 5}  
{5 , 4 , 3 , 210 , 1}  
{4 , 5 , 1 , 210 , 3}  
{2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 1}  
{3 , 4 , 5 , 110 , 2}
```

I hope the example makes my problem clear. Thank you!

Comment: In what way is the output you need different than the output you currently get?

Comment: @Eran I just updated the question. I hope now it is clear what my problem is. It is just adding the value but not calculating it.

Comment: @boersencrack it looks like you are appending strings. How does `excelMatrix` look like

Comment: What are you trying to calculate with it? It might be useful to post more of the code, i.e. the method where you're meant to calculate using the data.

Comment: is ur `excelMatrix` an int array or a `2d char array` ?

Comment: The algorithm is fine, can you update the question with excelMatrix type?

Comment: @Matt I just added more code to my question.

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera I just did.

Comment: @a874 actually it is a double array.

Comment: What's the definition of 'excelMatrix', pls show the full code

Comment: @yellowB I am taking 'excelMatrix' from an excel file and save it as a String. Afterwards I am converting it to a double array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the output you are getting, it looks like the type of `excelMatrix` is `String[][]`, so when you are using the `+=` operator you are concatenating a number to a String.

If you change your `excelMatrix` array to `int[][]`, you'll get the desired output.

If `excelMatrix` must remain a `String[][]`, you can still perform the addition by converting the `String` to `int`, performing addition and converting back to `String` (though that would be less efficient) :

```
excelMatrix[r][column] = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(excelMatrix[r][column]) + value);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet will solve your problem.

```
for(int i =0;i<numOfRows;i++) {
    for(int j= 0;j<numOfColumns;j++) {
       if(i != rowToBeSkipped) {
         excelMatrix[i][j] = excelMatrix[i][j] + value;
        }
    }
}
```